# How to customise JQuery Filedrop to send dynamic post data variables?

Tags: jquery, variables, post

I'm using the excellent Jquery-Filedrop [weixiyen] used by tutorialzine and I'm stuck on a problem trying to send dynamic POST variables, explained as follows:

I have an html form select drop-down (photo_tab_index) where user can choose a slideshow number (say 1-5) and then a dropbox canvas where the user drops their photos onto to upload to the web server.

In the filedrop javascript I have the following:

```
$(function(){
  var dropbox = $('#dropbox'),
  message = $('.message', dropbox);

  var slideshow = document.getElementById('photo_tab_index').value;

  dropbox.filedrop({
    // The name of the $_FILES entry:
    paramname:'pic',
    data: {
      param1: slideshow,           // send POST variables
    },
    ...

    // Called before each upload is started
    beforeEach: function(file){
      if(!file.type.match(/^image\//)){
        alert('Only images are allowed!');
        return false;
      }
    },
    ...
```

The problem I have is that the javascript reads the value of the photo_tab_index when it renders the page (and hence are always sent as "1") but what I really want is for it to read the slideshow dropdown value at the point that photos are dropped on the drop box. In my limited JQuery knowledge I have a feeling that I want to be updating the dropbox.filedata "data: param1" field in the beforeEach: function but I'm not sure how I would reference it?

Comment: DOH! I think I might have found the answer looking back at the original usage example. You can specify

     data: { 
       param1: 'value1',
       param2: function(){
            return calculated_data; // calculate data at time of upload
       },
     },

But where does the calculated_data come from? Is this a function like beforeEach created further down?

Comment: Yes, in fact that got it ... so change param1 to be a function() and then inside the curly braces call the "var slideshow = document.getElementById('photo_tab_index').value;" ... perfect. Sorry for the time waster, but the process of writing it out somehow clears the brain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So to conclude for those having the same problem, you can use the example param2 function to calculate the POST variable at the point of uploading, so:

```
data: {
   param2: function(){
       var slideshow = document.getElementById('photo_tab_index').value;     
       return slideshow; // calculate data at time of upload,           
   },     
},
```

Comment: it definitely was NOT a time waste.. You just helped me out with this.. I am basically doing the same thing as you.. getting the user select a gallery from a dropdownlist and upload photos into it..

Comment: Genius!  Fantastic!  Tour de force!

Comment: What would you suggest doing if the element can't be referenced via an Element Id, because it has been created dynamically or with a foreach statment?

I've tried doing a `$(this).closest('.manageContainer').attr("data-id");` but it seems `$(this)` no longer refers to the calling element.

Comment: @KemalEmin forgot to tag you

Comment: Hi Darrell, thanks for posting your answer. I was doing exactly the same as you and forgot about using a function for a parameter. Now changed my code to use a function and is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent. It helps us a lot. Yes, to make the right value of dynamic data, what you need to do is to attach a new function with returning your expected one. Thanks a lot.